# Could not create the Java virtual machine OSX10.9

Tags: java, macos

Can't seem to find an answer to this.

If I type `java -version` I get

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

I'm trying to run [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/) to analyse an iOS project. When I run the command in Terminal however, I get:

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to installation issue. Check whether you have installed correct JRE for your platform(bit pattern etc.). If its fine try changing memory settings.

[This link will help you to set memory settings in Java](http://www.jafaloo.com/java-xmx-memory-settings/)